# Embedding flv (flash) player in WPF app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, flash

Is there a method to embed ANY flash Player/activx to WPF application to play FLV files?

I am guessing also if it is possible to add some JS code to WPF WebBrowser control and play video there?

Is it good approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If embed code contains an `iframe`, take the `src` of `iframe` and put it into `WebBrowser` source.

For example, for Youtube videos this is the embed code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" 
 src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/[youtubeVideoId]" 
 frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

You will use this url in your WPF WebBrowser:

> http://www.youtube.com/embed/[youtubeVideoID]

Similar for other sites.